# Как сделать free/paid версии игры для Google Play?

Tags: google-play

Здравствуйте!

Я только-только осваиваю геймдев, однако уже кое-как сумел написать первую игру. Каким образом мне как можно более просто организовать две версии, платную (без рекламы) и бесплатную (с рекламой)?

Сомнения: это мне надо будет подгружать в Google Play два разных APK, как будто просто две разных игры? А как же будут уживаться два одинаковых имя? А как же одинаковые пакеты и вообще структура проектов? Мнея за это не забанят?

Реализацию In-app покупки пока не потяну из-за сложности кода и отсутствующих знаний/практики.

Comment: одинаковые пакеты вам выложить не дадут точно. Но поменять имя пакета не очень большая сложность. Проблем с баном из-за одинаковой структуры не возникет, если вы выложите всё это на один аккаунт.

Comment: Ок, спасибо! Значит попробую сделать две игры: Super Game Free и Super Game.